# How to limit I/O consumption of Python processes (possibly using ionice)?

Tags: python, linux, performance, unix

I would like a particular set of Python subprocesses to be as low-impact as possible.  I'm already using [nice](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/nice/) to help limit CPU consumption.  But ideally I/O would be limited as well.  (If skeptical, please humor me and assume there is value in doing this; it doesn't matter how long they take to run, there can be a lot of them, and there is higher-priority stuff (usually) going on on the same machine, etc.)

One possibility appears to be `ionice`.  Are there any existing Python packages for invoking `ionice` (Google didn't turn up anything)?  It wouldn't be difficult to write code to simply run the `ionice` command; but I'd prefer to avoid writing code that someone else has written/tested; sometimes there are subtle edge cases, etc.  And, is there just a better way to limit I/O consumption?

The [man page for ionice](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ionice) suggests that the `ionice` value can be affected by the `nice` value, but running this Python 2.6 script appears to disprove that, even for child processes where the `nice` value is inherited:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import multiprocessing

def print_ionice(name):
    print '*** ', name, ' ***'
    os.system("echo -n 'nice: '; nice")
    os.system("echo -n 'ionice: '; ionice -p%d" % os.getpid())

for niced in (None, 19):
    if niced: os.nice(niced)
    print '**** niced to: ', niced, ' ****'
    print_ionice('parent')
    subproc = multiprocessing.Process(target=print_ionice, args=['child'])
    subproc.start()
    subproc.join()
```

Which has the following output:

```
$ uname -as
Linux x.fake.org 2.6.27-11-server #1 SMP Thu Jan 29 20:13:12 UTC 2009 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ ./foo.py
**** niced to:  None  ****
***  parent  ***
nice: 0
ionice: none: prio 4
***  child  ***
nice: 0
ionice: none: prio 4
**** niced to:  19  ****
***  parent  ***
nice: 19
ionice: none: prio 4
***  child  ***
nice: 19
ionice: none: prio 4
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[psutil](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/) exposes this functionality (python 2.4 -> 3.2):

```
import psutil, os
p = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
p.ionice(psutil.IOPRIO_CLASS_IDLE)
```

Also, starting from Python 3.3 this will be available in python stdlib as well:
http://bugs.python.org/issue10784

Comment: Cool fix, wish it was available for OSX.

Comment: yeah... unfortunately OSX just does not expose it natively.

Comment: Make sure your block device has CFQ scheduler. Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: The issue you linked to makes no mention of `ionice` (or `ioprio_get`/`ioprio_set`). That functionality is still missing in the Python standard library, except as implemented by e.g. @tzot 's solution. Only `getpriority`/`setpriority` have been implemented.

Answer (score 5):

Hm.

As a start pointer, you should find what `syscall` number are the `ioprio_set` and `ioprio_get` system calls in your kernel. I'd suggest you check in `/usr/include/asm/unistd_32.h` or `/usr/include/asm/unistd_64.h`, depending on your kernel arch; if not there, start with the suggestion of the `syscall(2)` man page, which should be `/usr/include/sys/syscall.h` and work your way down includes.

Given that, you should use `ctypes`, à la:

```
def ioprio_set(which, who, ioprio):
    rc= ctypes.CDLL('libc.so.6').syscall(289, which, who, ioprio)
    # some error checking goes here, and possibly exception throwing
```

That's it, more or less. Have fun :)

Answer (score 3):

Why not have whatever *launches* the processes do the ionice on them (i.e., run them with ionice) rather than having them ionice themselves?  It seems a whole lot cleaner.

Comment: I effectively want to fork and not exec (e.g., using the 'multiprocessing' module); unsure where ionice would fit in there.  The children *could* call ionice -p<pid> -cblah (on themselves, e.g., using os.system).

Comment: @JacobGabrielson Since Linux kernel version 2.6.13 child processes will inherit their parent's `nice` values and receive a default `ionice` class of 2, which gives it a best-effort priority between 0 and 7 calculated by `(nice + 10 ) // 5`. So you should be able to control it that way.